# Error Message while running Hive

Tags: hive

```
CREATE TABLE CCTGDB_TMP.ODS_WORLDWIDE_AR_REVENUE_R12_C3_TEMP_1 (
  ENTERED_CR DOUBLE,
  ACCOUNTED_CR DOUBLE,
  ENTERED_DR DOUBLE,
  ACCOUNTED_DR DOUBLE,
  INVOICE_CURRENCY_CODE STRING,
  CURRENCY_CODE STRING,
  CODE_COMBINATION_ID   DOUBLE,
  JE_SOURCE STRING,
  USER_JE_SOURCE_NAME STRING,
  SEGMENT1 STRING,
  SEGMENT2 STRING,
  SEGMENT3 STRING,
  SEGMENT4 STRING,
  SEGMENT5 STRING,
  SEGMENT6 STRING,
  PERIOD_NAME STRING,
  LEDGER_ID DOUBLE,
  NAME STRING,
  PERIOD_YEAR DOUBLE,
  PERIOD_NUM DOUBLE,
  END_DATE STRING,
  USER_JE_CATEGORY_NAME STRING,
  REVENUE_USD   DOUBLE
)
COMMENT 'Adjustment  Revenue'
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
STORED AS PARQUET;
```

I'm getting the error below:

```
FAILED: ParseException line 8:25 cannot recognize input near ',' 'JE_SOURCE' 'STRING' in column type
```

Comment: I have created the table with above command and it is working for me , may be you have some extra characters at CODE_COMBINATION_ID   DOUBLE,JE_SOURCE STRING please check once.

Answer (score 0):

yes it is working fine. due to some extra characters